# can the expression "by car" be used in the sentence below?

Tags: expression-choice

We are on the way to church by car.
Is this a correct sentence?
I am not sure if it is ok to use the phrase "by car" other than go, come, reach, get to or arrive?
Thanks.

Comment: It's perfectly normal. As opposed to *by bus* or *by foot*.